# How to render data as it streams in from api

Tags: next.js, rendering

In a similar way to chatgpt's style of rendering new text as the user receives it, Im trying to replicate this by rendering the new data I receive from the api Im using (deepinfra).
I can get 'chunks' as they are sent to me and log them to the console, but next.js 14 makes me use a server component for that part.

The solution I tried to implement was a useState, passed to the api function that was meant to edit the content of the Chat component.

All of the weird iterations ai has suggested to me has resulted in a loop of 'useState cannot be used in a server function' OR 'setContent is not a function'

Current version of 'Chat.js'

```
use client";

import getResponse from "../api/chat/getResponse";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Chat = () => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await getResponse("Hello, I am a human. What are you?");
        setContent(response); // Assuming the response contains the content you want to set
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
        // Handle the error gracefully, e.g., setContent("Error fetching data");
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log(content);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{content}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

Current version of 'getResponse.js'

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default async function getResponse(prompt, setContent) {
  const API_KEY = process.env.DEEPINFRA_KEY;

  try {
    const response = await axios.post('https://api.deepinfra.com/v1/openai/chat/completions', {
      model: "lizpreciatior/lzlv_70b_fp16_hf",
      messages: [{ role: "user", content: prompt }],
      max_tokens: 20,
      stream: true,
    }, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        authorization: `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
      },
      responseType: 'stream', // Set the response type to stream
    });

    const stream = response.data; // Get the response stream

    stream.on("data", (chunk) => {
      const toString = chunk.toString().replace("data: ", "");
      if (toString.includes("[DONE]")) return;
      const toJSON = JSON.parse(toString);
      const newContent = toJSON.choices[0].delta.content;
      console.log(newContent === undefined ? "" : newContent);
      setContent(newContent);
    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    // Handle the error gracefully, e.g., setContent("Error fetching data");
  }
}
```

Im using next.js 14 with turbo enabled.
Thanks for all of the help!